# Falsk "ssl_context" to point to SSL certificate issued by Google

Tags: flask, https, ssl-certificate, gcloud

I have a Flask app running within a google cloud instance. I'v configured a custom domain and I'm able to access my app from chrome using the `adhoc` ssl_context. I understand that for prod enviroments, it's better to install a proper SSL certificate instead of `adhoc` in order to serve HTTPS requests.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context='adhoc')
```

I'v issued a Google managed SSL certificate following these instructions
https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs

1. Do I need to configure an additional certificate for the `ssl_context` in flask?
2. Can I reuse Google's SSL certificate and if so, how? I'm unable to access Google's SSL crt and key.pem files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing your questions:

1. No, you don't need anything else in the ssl_context.
   I understand that when you code

   `app.run(ssl_context='adhoc')`

   you are using a self-signed certificate.
   The [recommendation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#migrating_to_google-managed_certificates_from_self-managed_certificates) is not to stop using your self-signed certificate until the Google-managed ssl certificate is active.
2. No, you are using a Google-managed ssl certificate; the certificate can only be used for the domains you requested it.
    Here are some other [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#limitations) you might be interested in.